# Rails: Customize Devise Confirmable module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have my Rails app setup with [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), but it's still in the development stages. I also have a Thor task that creates the default Admin user.

Problem is Devise won't let that admin user login to the site until the account is confirmed. Is there any way I can disable the confirmable module for the creation of specific users, such as Admin?

My Thor task:

```
class Setup < Thor
  desc "create_admin [EMAIL] [PASSWORD]", "Creates the administrative user."
  def create_admin(email = "admin@bogus.com", password = "testpassword123")
    require File.expand_path('config/environment.rb') # load Rails environment
    admin = User.create(:email => email, :password => password, :password_confirmation => password)
    admin.assign_role :admin
    puts "Admin user (#{ email }) created."
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once your user is created you can call the devise provided confirm! method on it rather than updating the database directly. Eg.:

```
admin = User.create(:email => email, :password => password, :password_confirmation => password)
admin.assign_role :admin
admin.confirm!
```

Comment: This also has the additional benefit of not needing to make `confirmed_at` an accessible attribute which could make it possible for users to confirm themselves without going through the actual confirmation process!

Comment: Ahh, thanks for that.  I was creating users in seed data and was passing a confirmed_at value, but it just ignores it.  You have to go through the confirm method.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
admin = User.create(:email => email, :password => password, :password_confirmation => password)
```

So your confirmed_at is set, which is the field devise refers to when checking user confirmation.

**EDIT**

Forgive me if this seems like a hack but this seems to work for me. After executing the above line,

```
admin.update_attributes(:confirmed_at => Time.now)
```

Comment: I did that, but the User is still being created with `confirmed_at` as `nil`. What gives?

Comment: No, still registering as `nil`.

Comment: Your `update_attributes` didn't work, but if I manually set the value and save the record, it does: `admin.confirmed_at = Time.now \ admin.save`. Why doesn't this work when specified in the `create` method or with the `update_attributes` method? Both of those seem much cleaner than having to do it manually as I just described...

Comment: Ok, I feel retarded: I forgot to add `confirmed_at` to my list of accessible attributes in my model (via `attr_accessible`). Your first method works as expected now. My bad. Thanks!

Comment: If you are making `confirmed_at` an accessible attribute that could be quite dangerous as it would allow users to confirm themselves if they crafted their own post attributes. See my `.confirm!` approach for a saner way to approach this.

Answer (score -1):

just coment `:confirmable` in User or Admin model

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, #:confirmable...
```

In config/inicializers/devise.rb
you can set here how many time user have to confirm his account

Comment: My admin user is of type User; I still want :confirmable to be used on every other type of User, just not admin.